# Auto generate w3wp.exe process dump file when CPU threshold is reached even when PID changes

Tags: pid, w3wp, procdump

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with one of our websites which causes the CPU to spike intermittently. The site sits on a farm of web servers and it intermittently happens across all servers at different times. The process which causes the spike is w3wp.exe. I have checked all the obvious things and now want to analyse multiple sets of dump files for the w3wp.exe which causes the spike.

I'm trying to automatically generate a dump file of the w3wp.exe process when it reaches a specified CPU threshold for a specified time.

I can use ProcDump.exe to do this and it works a treat IF it's fired before the PID (Process ID) changes.

For example:
`procdump -ma -c 80 -s 10 -n 2 5844`(where 5844 is the PID)

- -ma Write a dump file with all process memory. The default dump format includes thread and handle information.
- -c CPU threshold at which to create a dump of the process.
- -s Consecutive seconds CPU threshold must be hit before dump written (default is 10).
- -n Number of dumps to write before exiting.

The above command would monitor the w3wp.exe till CPU spikes 80% for 10 seconds and it would take full dump at least for two iterations.

**The problem:**

I have multiple instances of w3wp.exe running so I cannot use the Process Name, I need to specify the PID. The PID changes each time the App Pool is recycled. This causes the PID to change before I can capture multiple dump files. I then need to start procdump again on each web server.

**My question:**

How can I keep automatically generating dump files even after the PID changes?

Answer (score 2):

USe DebugDiagnostic 2.0 from Microsfot: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924

It handles multiple w3wp.exe processes. If you need a generic solution, you will have to write a script - such as https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Getting-SysInternals-027bef71